# How do I put a calculation inside a for loop with an if statement in between? What is the correct syntax?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, if-statement, syntax

With the use of my for loop looping backwards I want to get every other digit, double it and check if that number is bigger than 9. If the number is bigger than 9, I want to subtract nine from it. I want to do this in one function. Maybe use a built in function. This is what I got so far:

```
const validateCred = array => {
  for (let i = array.length -2; i >= 0; i = i -2 ) {
    let multiply = array[i] * 2;
    if (multiply > 9) {
      let minusNine = multiply -9;
    }
  }
};
```

Any suggestions would be a big help!

Comment: Where's the connection between the title and the script in the body? What's the purpose of `minusNine`? What is `validateCred()` supposed to do?

Comment: The calculation is the *2 and the -9 inside the for loop, the if statement comes in between as you can see. \This exercise is part of a bigger one for checking if creditcardnumbers are valid or not. You start from the right excluding the check digit(the most right digit) and iterate over every other digit which you have to double, and if doubling the digit makes it greater than 9 you''ll have to subtract nine from it. Lastly you have to sum all the numbers and check if (modulo)%10 = 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- first You need an array to store numbers for iterated array `res`.
- to iterate backwords you must start with `array.length - 1` not `-2` or you will lost last one.
- to iterated over all numbers decrement the `i` with `-1`

```js
const validateCred = array => {
  const res = [];
  for (let i = array.length -1; i >= 0; i = i -1 ) {
    let multiply = array[i] * 2;// double it
    if (multiply > 9) {//check if that number is bigger than 9
      let minusNine = multiply -9;//subtract nine from it
            res.push(minusNine);
    }else{
      res.push(array[i]); //just store as it is.
    }
  }
  return res.reverse()
};
validateCred([10,3,40,9]);// [11, 3, 71, 9]
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it helped a lot!